# Is there anyway paste a RGBA image on a color blank but still keep alpha channel as it before?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is my code:

```
new_img = Image.new('RGBA', (new_size, new_size))
new_img.paste(img, (delta_w,delta_h))
new_img.split()[-1].save('5.png')

new_img = Image.new('RGB', (new_size, new_size), color)
new_img.paste(img, (delta_w,delta_h), mask=img)
new_img.save('4.png')
```

please tell me is there another way shorter and faster

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title. And what is `img`? I don't understand which one have to keep alpha channel.

Comment: maybe you should create blank with `Alpha channel` or maybe you should assign original alpha layer to some variable and later add it back to original image. `PIL` can split image to separated layers/channels and later it can join/merge layers/channels back to image.

Comment: OR maybe you should work with `numpy.array` instead of `PIL.Image` and it allow to add values on selected layers